# Send websocket message to concrete frontend user from Spring Boot application

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, websocket

*(I know there are a lot of posts about sending messages to specific users but for some reason I don't understand (it must be a small thing I can't see), none of them helped me.)*

**What works**

- Backend/Server - running WebSocket server and accepting communication; Adding local user ID to message using `StompHeaderAccessor` in `ChannelInterceptor`
- Frontend - connecting WS server, creating a session, sending a user message from FE to BE

**Situation:** I'm trying to set up two-way communication between the Websocket server (Spring) and the JavaScript frontend. But I am not able to send a message for concrete user from backend back to frontend.

**WebSocket configuration:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@AllArgsConstructor
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 99)
public class WebSocketConfiguration implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(WebSocketConfiguration.class);

  private final WebSocketLoginHashService webSocketUserLoginService;

  @Override
  public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/ws").withSockJS();
  }

  @Override
  public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
    registration.setInterceptors(new UserInterceptor(webSocketUserLoginService));
  }

  @Override
  public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    registry.enableSimpleBroker("/queue");
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    registry.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user/");
  }
}
```

**Interceptor `UserInterceptor`**

```
public class UserInterceptor implements ChannelInterceptor {

  private static String AUTH_HEADER = "Authorization";
  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserInterceptor.class);

  private final WebSocketLoginHashService userWebSocketLoginHashService;

  @Override
  public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {

    StompHeaderAccessor accessor = MessageHeaderAccessor.getAccessor(message, StompHeaderAccessor.class);

    if (StompCommand.CONNECT.equals(accessor.getCommand())) {

      final Optional<UUID> tokenFound = parseAuthToken(message);

      if (tokenFound.isPresent()) {
        if (this.userWebSocketLoginHashService.exists(tokenFound.get())) {
          accessor.setUser(new WebSocketAuthUser(tokenFound.get()));
        } else {
          throw new BadCredentialsException("Autentizacni token neni validni: " + tokenFound.get());
        }
      }
    
    }

    return message;
  }

}
```

**Frontend** - connection to server and subscribe to user related events (doesn't work), sending message back to server (works).

```
function connect(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    $.getJSON("/api/ws/", function (data) {

        var socket = new SockJS('/ws');
        stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);

        stompClient.connect({'Authorization': data.data.hash}, function (frame) {

            // Subscribe to user related events
            stompClient.subscribe('/user/queue/notify', function (payload) {
                console.log("Payload received:" + payload.body);
            });

            // Send message back to server
            var message = {
                "name": "John"
            };
            var stringMessage = JSON.stringify(message);
            stompClient.send("/app/hello", {}, stringMessage);

        });

    });

}
```

**Problem:** - when I try to send message back to user, message to frontend user never arrives.

```
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
  @GetMapping(value = "/", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public @ResponseBody void index() {

    final Optional<WebSocketLoginHashService.Record> uuid =
        this.userWebSocketLoginHashService.get(new UserId(1L));

    if (!uuid.isPresent()) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Authorized User not found!");
    }

    String sessionId = uuid.get().getHash().toString();
    String payload = "Payload for user (session: " + sessionId + ")";

    SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headers = SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.create(SimpMessageType.MESSAGE);
    headers.setSessionId(sessionId);
    headers.setLeaveMutable(true);

    simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(sessionId, "/queue/notify", payload, headers.getMessageHeaders());
    simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(sessionId, "/user/queue/notify", payload, headers.getMessageHeaders());
  }
```

Why are not messages delivered to FE user?